The movstd function swaps output matrix dimensions?
I've noticed that the movstd function swaps the dimensions of my matrix.
My input is Mdata_rs a 3x5x100 matrix and the output movSTDdata_rs is a 5x100x3 matrix. I tested with a smaller 3D matrices (2x3x5) and it works fine. Did I miss something in the documentation?
Here is my code :
clear; close all; clc;

xlist = 1:5;
ylist = (1:3)*10;

% Making a LUT from x and y : LUT --> nConf | x | y
count = 1;
for kx=1:length(xlist)
 for ky=1:length(ylist)
   LUT(count,:) = [count xlist(kx) ylist(ky)];
   count = count+1;
   end
end

% Making the data --> nConf | measurement
% data :  1 x1
%         2 x2
%        ...
%        15 x15
%         1 x16
%         2 x17
%        ...
Nrounds = 100;
data = zeros(Nrounds*length(LUT),2); % Let's have a multiple rounds/cycles measurements
data(:,2) = rand(length(data),1); % Random measurements
data(1:floor(Nrounds)*length(LUT),1) = repmat(LUT(:,1),[floor(Nrounds) 1]); % Fill the nConf column

% Parameter to compute a noise approximation
wlen = 3; % window length
opt = 0; %see movstd doc

%% Reshaping the data in a 3D matrix with each column in the third axis is a conf with Nrounds layers
Mdata_rs = reshape(data(:,2),[length(ylist) length(xlist) Nrounds]);
movSTDdata_rs = movstd(Mdata_rs,wlen,opt,3);
output1 = median(movSTDdata_rs,3); %Get a noise approximation ignoring the possible base line

I've run it with matlab and there is no issue.
I know I can go around it by using reshape() to get the right order but I would like to know why or at least when this behaviour appears.

So this is the reason you had this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78677682/7328782 — This seems like a bug, you should open a ticket in the Octave bug tracker.

@CrisLuengo Well, yes and no. I was working on the same code but these are two separate issues with different behaviour and implications.

Well, it perfectly explains why that code gives different answers in MATLAB and Octave. Also, if the Octave code is wonky by swapping dimensions, it might be doing something else wrong too.

Note that the movSTDdata_rs = reshape(movSTDdata_rs,[length(ylist) length(xlist) Nrounds]); in your linked code does not fix the problem of swapped dimensions. reshape does not swap dimensions. You can test to see if you're running on Octave, and use permute to order the dimensions like they are in the MATLAB result.

@CrisLuengo You're right. In general it wouldn't work, but turns out in my case it does :-)

No, it doesn't work in your case either. You think it does, but it doesn't. If it did work, you likely wouldn't be getting different results in MATLAB and Octave.

this appears to affect all movX functions.  you can simply do:  a = rand(3,6,4); movmean(a,3,1), movmean(a,3,2), movmean(a,3,3) to see that when dim is 3 the shape of the return is incorrect. i think these functions do an internal permute to always move the operating dimension to the same dimension, with an ipermute at the end.  probably something wrong there. should file a report at bugs.octave.org

@NickJ Yes, movfun permutes the dim to the first and then permutes it back. However I could not understand if it was done correctly or not. The thing is, it does not seem to always be the case.

bug report filed

It appears that there is a bug in movefun (called by movstd, movmean, etc.) in Octave 9.2.0.  The function reshapes/permutes the input to flatten it to 2D and put the operating dimension into columns for simpler coding of the windowing operations.  The function ends by restoring the shape, first by unflattening it with reshape, then by reversing the dim permutation.  Unfortunately, it appears that the code should have used ipermute, not permute, and this issue only appeared when operating on dim > 2, and there were no self tests for nD data to catch that issue.
A bug report has been opened at
https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?65927
That will hopefully be fixed before version 9.3.0.  In the meantime, it appears that correct functionality can be restored to your code by changing line 297 from:
 y = permute (y, [dperm, nd+1]);
to
 y = ipermute (y, [dperm, nd+1]);
UPDATE:  A patch has been submitted to fix this bug.  It should be available as part of Octave 9.3.0.  If the fix is needed in the meantime, the 1-character fix above can be made to the movfun.m file in v9.2.0 (typing edit movfun within Octave).
